# What is a good pattern to keep changes to a hierarchical object persisted?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, serialization

Consider that we have a similar object hierachy as illustrated below where a `User` has a group of `Profiles` and each profile a group of `Settings`.

```
class User {
   private final List<Profile> profiles;
}

class Profile {
   private final List<String> settings;
}
```

What is a good way ensure that any changes to the above objects are also persisted to disk? The assumption is that a `Profile` can be big and I want to avoid persisting the entire `User` for a modification in a `Profile`.

Note that it's a design issue, not an issue about selecting the right object serialization library.

Comment: Have you thought about storing only difference which has been done since last sync? You could even replay changes then.

Comment: Also there is something called structural sharing - maybe this idea could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ensure that any changes to the above objects are also persisted to disk?

The short answer, if you're talking about design, is to make user an aggregate root, and let user maintain the consistency of the the object hierarchy it owns.

> avoid persisting the entire User for a modification in a Profile.

Sounds like you need event-sourcing in this case.
In short you need to store changes made to profiles/settings. And reconstruct profiles/settings, upon loading User, from the stream of events (facts) which is the changes made so far.

Take time to look at this:
[CQRS and event sourcing by Greg Young @ YouTube](https://youtu.be/JHGkaShoyNs)